# How to refresh a nested Component view that shows the result for a search being done in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a dropdown/select for month field and a button which can be clicked to see result for that month.

As in the code below, on clicking the button it sets the query month and changes the `ShowResultForMonth` component visible.

On click also passes the query month to the component so it renders the result of the nested component correctly. But When i select a new month and click the button again it does not refresh the nested component's view and shows result from the first queried month.

How can we refresh the nested component when i resubmit the selection?

```
export default class MonthSearch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            queryYear: '',
            months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
            detailVisible: false
        };
    }

    onMonthChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ queryMonth: event.target.value });
    }

    onSend = (event) => {
        this.setState({ detailVisible: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.onMonthChange}>
                    {this.state.months.map((mt) => <option key={mt.value} value={mt.value}>{mt.display}</option>)}
                </select>
                <button onSubmit={this.onSend}>
                    Search
                </button>
                { this.state.detailVisible ?
                    <ShowResultForTheMonth queryMonth={this.state.queryMonth} />
                    : <h3>select month</h3>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your example work? `button` doesn't support the onSubmit prop, and items in your month array don't contain the display or value attribute.

Comment: I was trying to extract the necessary info. I can update it. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit fixed your example, it works fine.
Take a look, you'll figure out what's wrong with your code

```
export default class MonthSearch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      queryYear: "",
      months: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
      detailVisible: false
    };
  }

  onMonthChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ queryMonth: event.target.value });
  };

  onSend = (event) => {
    this.setState({ detailVisible: true });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onMonthChange}>
          {this.state.months.map((mt) => (
            <option key={mt} value={mt}>
              {mt}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <button onClick={this.onSend}>Search</button>
        {this.state.detailVisible ? (
          <ShowResultForTheMonth queryMonth={this.state.queryMonth} />
        ) : (
          <h3>select month</h3>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function ShowResultForTheMonth(props) {
  return (
    <p>{props.queryMonth}</p>
  );
}
```

Comment: Serega can we make the `ShowResultForTheMonth` component update only when we click the `Search` button? right now once we search it renders the `ShowResult` but after that when we select month we don't have to click search and it just updates the view.

Comment: `ShowResultForTheMonth` re-renders once it got a new property. So if you want re-render it only after `Search` clicked - you can do next:

change your `detailVisible ` from boolean to `queryMonth ` that should be rendered by `ShowResultForTheMonth `. Like:

`
    this.state = {
      queryYear: "",
      months: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
      visibleMonth: null
    };
`

and then

`
onSend = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ visibleMonth: state. queryMonth }));
 };
`

Change condition for `ShowResultForTheMonth` rendering

`
{this.state.visibleMonth ? (
`